# Invalid Filter Type When Loading a File in Team Web Access

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a pretty straightforward problem. When I try to load a file through the Visual Studio 2010 Team Web Access, the new page comes up but with the error "Invalid Filter Type". I can't seem to find any information on this.

I'm using Team Foundation Server 2010 installed in Basic mode with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? Given your score, upload it to http://imgur.com/ and post the link, I'll put the image in the post.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Myself and a server admin looked into the issue and found there was a problem with the IIS extension schema (not sure if that's the correct term, but the list that controls what file extensions can be opened by the browser). It wasn't a Visual Studio or TFS Issue.